convert math formula to c#
I am trying to convert the formula below to C#:
Tw = T × arctan[0.151977 × (RH% + 8.313659)^(1/2)] + arctan(T + RH%) - arctan(RH% - 1.676331) + 0.00391838 ×(RH%)^(3/2) × arctan(0.023101 × RH%) - 4.686035

This is what I have so far:
double temp = 25;
double rh = 40;

var Tw = (temp * Math.Atan(0.151977 * (rh + 8.313659)) + Math.Atan(temp + rh) - Math.Atan(rh - 1.676331) + 0.00391838 * rh) ^ 3 / 2 * Math.Atan(0.023101 * rh) - 4.686035;

I keep getting the error:

^ cannot be applied to double and int.

Any help would be appreciated

Use Math.Pow for exponentiation. Operator ^ is for another operation (XOR).

Just to head off a likely future problem: 3/2 is going to be 1, not 1.5. You can write 3.0/2 or 3/2.0 or 3.0/2.0 or just 1.5, but 3/2 is not going to do what you need it to do. Same for 1/2 but see Math.Sqrt

You have your parentheses wrong! Look more closely at the formula.

If ^3/2 worked, it would first do 'to the power 3', then divide by 2. Use parentheses (and doubles)

There are several issues in the OP's code. Only one of them (the issue of operator^) is addressed in the dupe. Voted to reopen.

There are several issues in your code:

For exponentiation use Math.Pow.
Operator ^ is for something totally different - logical XOR (you can read about it here).
3 / 2 performs integer division since both 3 and 2 are integers. The result will be 1 (integer) and not 1.5 as you expect. In order to get what you need use 3.0 / 2 (3.0 is a double and will therefore cause to perform floating point division).
You seemed to miss the sqrt (^(1/2)) in your formula. You can use Math.Sqrt for that.
The parentheses in your code do not match the ones in the formula.

If I interpreted your formula correctly (are the parentheses in (RH%) before ^(3/2) on purpose?),
it should be something like:
double T = 25;
double RH = 40;

// formula:
//    Tw = T × arctan[0.151977 × (RH% + 8.313659)^(1/2)] +
//         arctan(T + RH%) - arctan(RH% - 1.676331) +
//         0.00391838 × (RH%)^(3/2) × arctan(0.023101 × RH%) -
//         4.686035
var Tw = T * Math.Atan(0.151977 * Math.Sqrt(RH + 8.313659)) + 
         Math.Atan(T + RH) - Math.Atan(RH - 1.676331) + 
         0.00391838 * Math.Pow(RH, 3.0/2) * Math.Atan(0.023101 * RH) - 
         4.686035;

Note that the formula is separated into several lines to improve readability.

@M_B thanks for accepting my answer ! Just in case you are not aware, you can also upvote it (as well as any useful answer), as voting and accepting is separate. See: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

Rather than write it all in one line, it can be clearer to split it over several lines, like this:
static public double WetBulbTemperature(double T, double RH)
{
    // Use the formula by Stull <https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/apme/50/11/jamc-d-11-0143.1.xml>
    var Tw = T * Math.Atan(0.151977 * Math.Sqrt(RH + 8.313659))
    + 0.00391838 * Math.Pow(RH, 1.5) * Math.Atan(0.023101 * RH)
    - Math.Atan(RH - 1.676331)
    + Math.Atan(T + RH)
    - 4.686035;

    return Tw;
}

C# doesn't have the exponentiation operator ^ present in some other languages (nor ** as in Fortran et al.), instead you need to use the Math.Pow() function. There is a special case for square roots: the Math.Sqrt() function.
Also, it's a good idea to include references to things like formulae—you might, for example, need to check the valid ranges of the parameters.

"it can be clearer to split it over several lines"  But this does not solve the "Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'double'", which weirdly differs from the message in OP ....

Ok, I cannot help someone found this useful, it not a reason to say (for /me) that it is not useful.... But /me still confuse about starting with "clearer to split it over several lines", which has nothing to do with the question.

@Luuk Maybe someone found the reference to the source of the equation useful. Anyway, responding to your first comment persuaded me to go and find one of the duplicates on SO.

In C#, the '^' operator is a bitwise XOR operator, not an exponentiation operator. To perform exponentiation in C#,use math.pow
